# what's the issue here?? webapi + angular + post

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Something weird is happening .... and I don't really understand why....
This post works **only if change the id parameter type from int to object.**

I know the best way is to set the value in the url... however I tried to avoid this thing... my preference is to post values as json

public IHttpActionResult Gettest(int id) =  don't work !

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:23052/api/testAPI/Gettest'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'testAPI' that matches the request."}

public IHttpActionResult Gettest(object id) = it works

> this runs nice

What am I doing wrong ?.... I tried to change the parameter name from "id" to "x" on server/client sides and I got the same result.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultActionApi", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
     [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Gettest(int id)
    {
        test test = db.tests.Find(id);
        if (test == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(test);
    }
```

testAPIController.cs

```
        $http.post("/api/testAPI/Gettest", id)
    .success(function (result) {


        $scope.test = result;


    }).error(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

angular  post

Comment: What if you try `int?` instead?

Comment: it didn't work... :S ...  I've just tried

Comment: change to public IHttpActionResult Gettest([FromUri] int id)

Comment: it didn't work.... the only way to make it works... it's to change type from int to object.... #LOL

Comment: @JorgeSolano could you please try what I suggested below.. It should work..

Answer (score 0):

Change your $http request to below. No need to write action method name, it will get called by controller name only. Web api works based on HTTP VERBS so just replace your request with below code:

```
$http.post("/api/testAPI/"+ id)
        .success(function (result) { 
            $scope.test = result;
        }).error(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
```